# Установка Google Tag Manager на сайт приводит к 500 ответу сервера

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtm

При установке кода Google Tag Manager или Google Analytics в тег , на фронтенде вылетает 500 ошибка.
Сайт на ImageCMS на фрейме Laravel, работает на php 5.6, все что выше/ниже не воспринимает.

Логи сервера:
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in .../www/system/cache/templates_c/86d7621155e7bc3551d0561a9a6373eb.php on line 7

Сам скрипт:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5HJWDN62');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Пробовал убирать "=", в логах пишет:
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in .../www/system/cache/templates_c/86d7621155e7bc3551d0561a9a6373eb.php on line 7

Кто сталкивался, подскажите, куда копать?